# What is using all my RAM in ubuntu? Hidden process?

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I'm running this command to view all processes listed by RAM usage:

`ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n`

and the largest one is 178MB

Yet when I run `glances` I see 96% of RAM used (10GB total)

When I sort by MEM% the highest one is my node server at 1.8%

It looks to me like there is some hidden process that takes up a lot of RAM.

I'm running a virtual machine.

OOM killer was shutting down my processes, this is how I found out the issue.

Comment: Are we talking about the “inside” of that virtual machine or the host system? Did you try `htop` yet? Have you checked for large `tmpfs` instances or RAM block devices?

Comment: as far as I can see, there is a similar case here in the best answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539640/no-100-memory-usage take a look at this thread.

Answer (score 1):

This is by intentional design. Memory is a "use or or lose it" resource. You can't save it for later. So modern operating systems try as hard as they can to use as much memory as they possibly can.

If you're thinking, "I want that memory free now so I can use it later", think a bit harder. You can use that memory now *and* use it later. There's no painful tradeoff here.

Say, for example, you run a program and it finished. The OS could keep that program in memory in case you run the program again. If it does, no harm is done. If the program isn't run again, the memory can just be discarded later. But if you do run that program again, I/O is saved as it doesn't have to be read in from disk. So the OS would rather leave copies of programs that recently executed in memory than have that memory free. This memory, of course, isn't associated with any process.

Comment: I had oom killer shutting down my processes

Comment: If you have a question about a particular problem, it's generally a good idea to mention the problem in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `free` command. You will likely see not much reported `Free`,  but likely quite a lot reported as `Available`. `man free` will tell you the difference.

Comment: I had oom killer shutting down my processes, I restarted my machine and now it's fine